# Check changes in a specific file for a specific commit, Git

Tags: git

I want check changes in a specific file for a specific commit (by its SHA1).

I have a SHA1 of a git commit - 16a75e59, in this commit several files was changed. I want check changes in only one of them - /www/htdocs/doms/js/Test.js.

I know that this file was changed int this commit:
If I run

`git show 16a75e59 | grep Test.js`

I got

`echo Resolve::minify( file_get_contents( '/www/htdocs/doms/js Test.js' ) );
diff --git a/www/htdocs/doms/js/Test.js b/www/htdocs/doms/js/Test.js
--- a/www/htdocs/doms/js/Test.js
+++ b/www/htdocs/doms/js/Test.js`

But when I trying

`git show 16a75e59 www/htdocs/doms/js/Test.js`

I got

`fatal: ambiguous argument 'www/htdocs/doms/js/Test.js': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Update: trying with -- and all works just fine. Seems first time I trying -- with leading slash.

So answer is: `git show 16a75e59 -- www/htdocs/doms/js/Test.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "doesn't work" you got a message like this one:

```
$ git show d8b396e /t/t7509-commit.sh
fatal: ambiguous argument '/t/t7509-commit.sh': unknown
revision or path not in the working tree.
```

(note: I split the line myself to make it fit better, it's all one line in the original), then it's because `/path/to/file.js` contains a leading slash.  Remove it:

```
$ git show d8b396e t/t7509-commit.sh
commit d8b396e17ecfe28b39b5f4470f791c434cce40ec
Author: Fabian Ruch ...
...
diff --git a/t/t7509-commit.sh b/t/t7509-commit.sh
index b61fd3c..9ac7940 100755
--- a/t/t7509-commit.sh
+++ b/t/t7509-commit.sh
```

(It helps if, in your original question, you show exactly the commands you use and the exact error messages.  This often avoids needing to guess at the problem.)

Comment: Yeah true, @Sergey Novikov, you should add more details like what you were expecting and what you got. Edit the post so it will be clear for us

Comment: Sagar Sakre, @torek, sorry for incomplete description. I updated it and after reading Git responce and this answer once more I figured out an error. Thanks! Henceforth, I will try to give the most detailed description of my problem. :)

Comment: Interesting; `git show <rev> <path>` *usually* works without the `--` separating <rev> and <path>.  The `--` is needed when the <path> part looks too much like other git options and such, but that should not be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try the `git diff` command

Check this

```
git diff SHA1^ SHA1 /path/to/file.js
```